# How is 'std::thread' is able to determine the number of variadic arguments passed to the constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, variadic-functions

When calling the constructor of `std::thread` you pass a function and its desired arguments. How does `std::thread` determine the total number of arguments meant to be passed to the function?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void task(int i, char c, bool b)
{
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::thread t(task, 10, 'c', true); // these 3 arguments
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Template magic.

Comment: It can use `sizeof...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`std::thread` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) is implemented using a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```cpp
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

Where:

- `Function` is the type of callable object that will be invoked by the thread (whether that be a function, a lambda, a functor, etc).
- `Args` is the list of types in the `args` variadic parameter.
- `f` is the actual callable object that the thread will invoke.
- `args` is the list of values that will be passed to `f`.

`std::thread` is then able to forward `args` to `f` using **parameter pack expansion**, *similar* to `f(args...);`.  The compiler itself, not `std::thread`, will expand `args...` to the actual values, ie: `f(arg1, arg2, ..., argN)`.

So, `std::thread t(task, 10, 'c', true);` will create a worker thread that make a call *similar* to to `f(args...)`, which will have been expanded to `task(10, 'c', true)`.

Thus, the arguments you pass to the `std::thread` constructor must match the arguments of the `f` callable you pass in, otherwise the code fails to compile.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::thread`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) has the form of

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

As you can see, the first argument is the function to run, and the rest are the arguments to be passed to it.  If those don't match, you get some sort of compiler error